# accessing RecyclerView item's view from another item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

if I click a `recyclarview` item it will unhide a `linearlayout` with buttons in itself. When I  click other item previous items's button segment will get hide. it's working fine but I am getting an error `(NullPointerException)` if previous item no longer in the visible area of `recyclarview`.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

```
    public class POAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<POAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG ="POAdapter" ;
    private List<PODatamodel> poList;
    public Context con;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private int prevPos=0;
    private FlipProgressDialog pd;
    private String userId;
    // OnDeleteCallback callback;

    /* public interface OnDeleteCallback {
        public void onPOItemDelete();
    }*/

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvTitle, tvDate, tvPrice;
        View mView;
        ConstraintLayout mainSegment, btnSegmnet;
        LinearLayout btnEdit, btnDel;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemNa);
            tvPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
            tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemDate);
            mainSegment = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.poMainSegment);
            btnSegmnet = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.poBtnSegment);
            btnEdit = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEditPO);
            btnDel = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDeletePO);
            mView = view;
        }
    }

    public POAdapter(List<PODatamodel> list, Context con) {
        this.poList = list;
        this.con = con;
    }

    public POAdapter(List<PODatamodel> list, RecyclerView rv, Context con ) {
        this.poList = list;
        this.con = con;
        this.rv = rv;

        SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(FAPI.SAVED_USER_DATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
        userId = pref.getString(FAPI.USER_ID, "null");

        pd = new FlipProgressDialog(con);
        pd.setMessage("Loading data...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setImage(R.drawable.ic_flogo2);
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.po_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final PODatamodel item = poList.get(position);
        Log.d("onBindPos", " holderpos: " + holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.tvTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.tvPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
        holder.tvDate.setText(item.getDate());
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Toast.makeText(con, "Under Development", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //  showDialog(con);
                if (holder.btnSegmnet.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    closePrevious(prevPos);
                } else {
                    closePrevious(prevPos);
                    holder.mainSegment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.btnSegmnet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    prevPos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                }
               // notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

        holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Toast.makeText(con, "Under Development", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(con, BuyActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(FAPI.OPENING_MODE,FAPI.EDIT);
                intent.putExtra(FAPI.PO_ID,item.getId());
                con.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String pdId = item.getId();
                Log.d("onDeleteClicked", "ID :" + pdId + " userId :" + userId);
                pd.show();

                deletePendingOrderItem(pdId, userId,holder.getAdapterPosition());
                //Toast.makeText(con, "Under Development ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // Log.d(tag, menuItemDataList.size() + "");
        return poList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public void deletePendingOrderItem(final String pdID, final String userID, final int pos) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(con).addToRequestQueue(
                new StringRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, FAPI.DELETE_PENDING_ORDER_ITEM(pdID, userID), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        pd.dismiss();
                        extractDataForDelete(response,pos);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        String msg = (error.getMessage() == null) ? " Something went wrong please try again" : error.getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(con, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("error", msg);
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("accept", "application/json");
                        params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        return params;
                    }

                   /* @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("email", email);
                        params.put("password", pass);
                        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(params));
                        return params;
                    }*/
                }
        );
    }

    public void extractDataForDelete(String json,int pos) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            String code = jsonObject.getString(FAPI.PO_DELETE_STATUS);
            if (code.equals(FAPI.DELETE_SUCCESS)) {
                String msg = jsonObject.getString(FAPI.PO_MESSAGE);
                Toast.makeText(con, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                poList.remove(pos);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
               /* if (callback != null)
                    callback.onPOItemDelete();*/
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public void closePrevious(int pos) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "closePrevious: " + pos);
            View mainSegment = rv.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(pos).findViewById(R.id.poMainSegment);
            View btnSegment = rv.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(pos).findViewById(R.id.poBtnSegment);
            btnSegment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mainSegment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        // Toast.makeText(con, v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



}
```

Comment: Instead of `View.GONE` try `View.INVISIBLE`

Comment: @amarok there's no problem with gone or invisible ,it's giving me NullPointerException  whenever i am calling closePrevious() method which hides the buttons of previous item.

Comment: @Mrinmoy, I'm struggling with a similar problem. Any chance you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding you are giving prevPos = 0 in every adapter position click.  Give a proper position in closePrevious method.

```
closePrevious(holder.getAdapterPosition());
```

Hope this will help you.